# Method declared with dynamic input parameter and object as return type in fact returns dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, visual-studio-2013

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var objectGetter = new ObjectGetter();
      var obj = objectGetter.GetItem(); //Visual Studio shows that obj type is System.Object
    }
  }

  public class ObjectGetter
  {
    public object GetItem()
    {
      dynamic dObj = "123";
      var obj = this.Convert(dObj);//Visual Studio shows that obj type is "dynamic" here. why???
      return obj;
    }

    private object Convert(dynamic dObj)
    {
      return new object();
    }
  }
}
```

I expected that `Convert` method call will return `System.Object` but in fact it returns `dynamic`. I can not understand why.

You can try to use any return type but result will be the same.

Comment: Since you marked it as `dynamic` until runtime, compiler has no idea what type it's actually is and so it would be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling a method with a `dynamic` argument. That means it's bound dynamically, and the return type is deemed to be dynamic. All you need to do is not do that:

```
object dObj = "123";
var obj = Convert(dObj);
```

Then the `Convert` call will be statically bound, and `obj` will have a type of `object`.

From the C# 5 specification, section 7.6.5:

> An invocation-expression is dynamically bound (§7.2.2) if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - The primary-expression has compile-time type dynamic.
> - At least one argument of the optional argument-list has compile-time type dynamic and the primary-expression does not have a delegate type.
>
> In this case the compiler classifies the invocation-expression as a value of type `dynamic`.

Comment: Thank you Jon. In real solution (WPF) I am using ExpandoObject() instances as dynamic binding targets for a grid. Will change dynamic to real type (ExpandoObject).